# Laravel facade __constructor() usage

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a class. The class's constructor assigns a value to a class property.

Here is the definition:

```
class myClass 
{
    private $_value;

    function __construct ($input)
    {
        $this->_value = $input;
    }

    function echoThat ()
    {
        echo $this->_value;
    }
}
```

And the regular usage is:

```
$x = new myClass("SimpleString");
$x->echoThat();
```

But I have turned the class into a facade type of class in Laravel so it is used:

```
myClass::echoThat();
```

How should I utilize the `__construct()` method in Laravel Facades like the above example?

Comment: OK tell me what is weird here

Comment: @M T - Developer: it's just a static class. Why do you think it's a *facade*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should only create a Laravel facade if you really want to use your class like Laravel facades are used. Laravel facades provide a static interface to a class.

This means either rewrite your class so that you can pass your string in anyother way like:

```
MyClassFacade::echoThat('SimpleString');
```

Of course you can also modify the underlying class to use for example another method to pass the string:

```
class MyClass 
{
    private $_value;

    public function setValue($val) 
    {
        $this->_value = $val;

        return $this;
    }

    public function echoThat()
    {
        echo $this->_value;
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
MyClassFacade::setValue('SimpleString')->echoThat();
```

You can call the non static methods of you class "statically" if you instantiate your class wherever the Laravel facade accessor is resolved, for example in the service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyClassServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('myclass', function()
        {
            return new MyClass();
        });
    }

}
```

Laravel will create an instance of `MyClass` whenever a method on your class is called statically using `__callStatic`.

Or don't use the Laravel facade and instantiate your class manually like you did it:

```
$x = new myClass("SimpleString");
$x->echoThat();
```

Comment: your explanation was quite clear and straightforward, without any insult...thanks

Comment: Your code is incorrect. You cannot use `$this` and statically call non static classes.

Comment: @M T - Developer: before checking an answer it makes sense to check that the provided code makes sense. Not the case here :-D

Comment: I was maybe not that clear. In this example `myClass` should be the underlying class of a facade. Ill try to make that more clear.

Comment: @Marcel Gwerder: You were not "not clear" but **incorrect**. "If you look for new in the laravel documentation you will not find it that often, it's because pretty much everything is done using facades." --- it's just **WRONG**. Please check what the facade is before you continue spreading what you're spreading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern It has **nothing** to do with either `new` or static classes. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @Marcel Gwerder: it doesn't matter what my answer should be. The fact is - that your answer is incorrect. Don't you agree? Please check the given link and count the `new` keyword entries there. Do you still think it has something to do with `new`? Do you still think "the facade" and "the static class" terms interchangeable? Do you still think your code will work?

Comment: @zerkms Can you proofread my answer once again? And to add that: The first time I've heard something about facades was when I started using Laravel. So I think I know how it works with Laravel and nothing more and that's also how I've written my answer, with Laravel in the back of my head.

Comment: @Marcel Gwerder: well, at least now it syntactically correct. But I wouldn't call it a "facade". Just because it doesn't - check the wikipedia for the *real* explanation of what it is. It's a buzz word introduced by laravel.

Comment: @zerkms Ok so you expect me to use a different word to describe something which is named a "facade" by the framework the asked question is all about? Ok maybe a Laravel facade is not a 100% match of a conventional facade but other than that it makes no sense for me to use another word no one understands. I can call it a "Laravel facade" from now on if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 6):

You have first to understand that a Facade, in Laravel, is not really your class, you must look at it, as the name says, a forefront or a frontage to your class. Facade is, acually, a Service Locator to your class.

To use this Service Locator you have to create a Service Provider, which will provide the service used by the Facade:

```
<?php namespace App\MyApp;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyClassServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['myclass'] = $this->app->share(function() 
        { 
            return new MyClass('the values you need it to instantiate with');
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array('myclass');
    }

}
```

Note that your class is instantiated in the method `register()` and now is available to your application via the IoC container, so you can do things like:

```
App::make('myclass')->echoThat();
```

And now you can also create your Facade to use it:

```
<?php namespace App\MyApp;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as IlluminateFacade;

class ExtendedRouteFacade extends IlluminateFacade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    { 
        return 'myclass'; 
    }

}
```

The Facade has only one method and its only purpose is to return the name of your class instance in the IoC container.

Now you can open your `app/config/app.php` and add the ServiceProvider:

```
'App\MyApp\MyClassServiceProvider',
```

also the actual Facade alias:

```
'MyClass' => 'App\MyApp\MyClassFacade',
```

and you should be good to use your Facade:

```
echo MyClass::echoThat();
```

But note that the way it is made your class `__constructor` will be always called with the same parameters, in your ServiceProvider, that's how a Facade works, but you have some options:

Use a setter to set a new value for the data in your class instance.

```
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->_value = $value;
}
```

Use the Laravel automatic class resolution to provide parameters for your class dinamically:

```
function __construct (MyFooClass $foo)
{
     $this->_foo = $foo;
}
```

And alter your ServiceProvider to provide **no parameters** to your class:

```
$this->app['myclass'] = $this->app->share(function() 
{ 
    return new MyClass();
});
```

Laravel will instantiante `MyFooClass` automatically for you, if it can locate it in the available source code of your application or if it's bound to the IoC container.

Note that all this assumes that you're not just passing a string in your constructor, the automatic resolution of the IoC container assumes your class has other class dependencies and inject those dependencies automatically (Dependency Injection).

If you really need to just pass strings or single values to constructors of classes that just do some calculations, you don't really need to create Facades for them, you can just:

```
$x = (new myClass("SimpleString"))->echoThat();
```

using a simple setter:

```
$x = new myClass();
$x->setValue("SimpleString");
$x->echoThat();
```

or, as you were already doing, which is acceptable:

```
$x = new myClass("SimpleString");
$x->echoThat();
```

And you can also use the IoC container to instantiate that class for you inside your other classes:

```
<?php

class Post {

    private $myClass;

    public function __construct(MyClass $myClass)
    {
        $this->myClass = $myClass;
    }

    public function doWhateverAction($value)
    {
        $this->myClass->setValue($value);

        // Do some stuff...

        return $this->myClass->echoThat();
    }

}
```

Laravel will automatically pass an instance of your class and you can use it the way you need:

```
$post = new Post;

echo $post->doWhateverAction("SimpleString");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some goode information about model classes in the Facede Lavarel FW in this page 
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

I assume here is the main explanation about your ploblem, the way to create a enter in database...

```
// Create a new user in the database...
$user = User::create(array('name' => 'John'));

// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$user = User::firstOrCreate(array('name' => 'John'));

// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
$user = User::firstOrNew(array('name' => 'John'));
```

And here the way to create a simple new instance and initialize its variables:

```
$user = new User;

$user->name = 'John';

$user->save();
```

Based on that I assume there isn´t a clear way to use a constructor in Lavarel.